# How do I bold (or format) a piece of text within a paragraph?

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I have a line of text with different formatting?

e.g.:

Hello **World**

Answer (score 439, accepted):

You should use the [RichText](https://docs.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) widget.

A RichText widget will take in a [TextSpan](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan-class.html) widget that can also have a list of children TextSpans.

Each TextSpan widget can have a different [TextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/TextStyle-class.html).

Here is the example code to render:
Hello **World**

```js
var text = RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
    // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
    style: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 14.0,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'Hello'),
      TextSpan(text: 'World', style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: This approach will ignore the font scaling specified by the phone, potentially impacting accessibility. For more details see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61802#issuecomment-660546228

Comment: `Text.rich` should be used to avoid the scaling issue.

Comment: Text.rich actually uses the app's default TextStyle - which could be very helpful. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64060239/3041394

Comment: This doesn't work with Localised strings right?

Answer (score 50):

#### [UPDATE]

The below answer fits best for couple of words and not for a paragraph,If you have a long sentence or a paragraph where you need to format a particular text prefer using RichText as suggested by @DvdWasibi in the above answer

#### [OLD ANSWER]

I like keeping my code short and clean this is How I Would do it add two text fields in a row one with Normal font and another **bold**,

**Note: This may not look good for a long paragraph looks good for Headlines etc.**

```js
Row(children: [
  Text("Hello"),
  Text("World", style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
]);
```

and you should get a desired output as "Hello **World**"

Comment: This is not a great idea, if you are going to have a paragraph of text. Each Text() inside the row create its own vertical/horizontal space.

Comment: so whats the alternative to using Row? and if I want text side by side with different formatting

Comment: look at above answer from @Dvdwasibi , just try your implementation with large paragraph and you will find kind of a two different paragraphs side by side. your answer is Correct for 2/3 words but not for a paragraph.

Comment: Agreed, thanks by the way I have updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 18):

```
return RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Can you ',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(
        text: 'find the',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.green,
          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
          decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy,
        ),
        recognizer: _longPressRecognizer,
      ),
      TextSpan(text: 'secret?'),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: when ceasing to be const `like 'my_string'.tr()` the texts are no longer inline, is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 13):

You should use the `Text.rich` constructor from `Text` class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html).

By using the `rich` constructor you can display a paragraph with differently styled `TextSpans`.

Why I recommended it instead of `RichText` is because of by using `RichText` you will required to define the parent `TextStyle` in `RichText` but using the `rich` constructor of `Text` you don't need explicitly defined the parent `TextStyle` in `Text.rich`

Here is the example how to use it with same result
Using `RichText`

```
const text = RichText(
  text: TextSpan( 
    // Here is the explicit parent TextStyle
    style: new TextStyle(
      fontSize: 16.0,
      color: Colors.black,
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat', 
    ),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      new TextSpan(text: 'Hello'),
      new TextSpan(text: 'World', style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    ],
  ),
 );
```

Using `rich` constructor of `Text`

```
const text = Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    // with no TextStyle it will have default text style
    text: 'Hello',
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'World', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: This way is better than RichText, because it's use correct TextStyle and textScaleFactor.

Answer (score 8):

I've solved a similar problem by using [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) widget with custom styles for different tags.
Actually, I've got the strings in different languages and some parts of them should be bold, so it wasn't easy to determine which part of the string I should make bold since strings was in l10n locale files. Here is example:

```
Container(
   child: Html(
              data: "<p>My normal text <b>with bold part</b> in any place</p>",
              style: {
                "p": Style(
                    fontSize: FontSize.large,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                "b": Style(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
    )
 );
```

I think this approach is useful in case you have a lot of differently styled text inside your regular text.

Answer (score 6):

Not fully tested but you can try this helper function that uses `Text.rich` and takes in the `fullText` and the `textToBold` then returns a Text:

```
static Text boldTextPortion(
    String fullText,
    String textToBold,
) {
    final texts = fullText.split(textToBold);
    final textSpans = List.empty(growable: true);
    texts.asMap().forEach((index, value) {
      textSpans.add(TextSpan(text: value));
      if (index < (texts.length - 1)) {
        textSpans.add(TextSpan(
          text: textToBold,
          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ));
      }
    });
    return Text.rich(
      TextSpan(
        children: <TextSpan>[...textSpans],
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: A practical solution, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

## Regex

You can use this widget. The example below always make numbers bold.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextBold extends StatelessWidget{
  final String text;
  final String regex;
  static const _separator = " ";

  const TextBold({Key key, this.text, this.regex = r'\d+'}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final parts = splitJoin();

    return Text.rich(TextSpan(
        children: parts.map((e) => TextSpan(
            text: e.text,
            style: (e.isBold)
                ? const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'bold')
                : const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'light')))
            .toList()));
  }

  // Splits text using separator, tag ones to be bold using regex
  // and rejoin equal parts back when possible
  List<TextPart> splitJoin(){
    assert(text!=null);

    final tmp = <TextPart>[];

    final parts = text.split(_separator);

    // Bold it
    for (final p in parts){
      tmp.add(TextPart(p + _separator,p.contains(RegExp(regex))));
    }

    final result = <TextPart>[tmp[0]];
    // Fold it
    if (tmp.length>1) {
      int resultIdx = 0;
      for (int i = 1; i < tmp.length; i++)
        if (tmp[i - 1].isBold != tmp[i].isBold) {
          result.add(tmp[i]);
          resultIdx++;
        }
        else
          result[resultIdx].text = result[resultIdx].text
              + tmp[i].text;
    }

    return result;
  }
}

class TextPart{
  String text;
  bool isBold;

  TextPart(this.text, this.isBold);
}
```

Comment: Not Working out of the box, For Future user replace both fontFamily with fontWeight: bold/ nomal and eureka works well !!!!!!!.

Comment: Can you add an example of how you would use this please?

Answer (score 1):

A sample code for a list of strings to bold as an argument and loops through them to find their positions in the full text. It then creates text spans with the appropriate style and returns a RichText widget. this is the modification of a given answer. with this you can bold multiple words/texts

```
RichText boldTextPortions(
  String fullText,
  List<String> textsToBold,
) {
  final textSpans = List.empty(growable: true);
  int start = 0;
  for (final textToBold in textsToBold) {
    final index = fullText.indexOf(textToBold, start);
    if (index != -1) {
      textSpans.add(TextSpan(text: fullText.substring(start, index)));
      textSpans.add(TextSpan(
        text: textToBold,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ));
      start = index + textToBold.length;
    }
  }
  textSpans.add(TextSpan(text: fullText.substring(start)));
  return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
    children: <TextSpan>[...textSpans],
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RichText()
```

Or if you receiving text from for example `'someText'.tr`,
so use **styled_text** pub package.