# Flutter: Is it possible to format (bold, italicize, etc) with-in the string only before passing to the text widget?

Tags: string, dart, flutter

For example :

```
String desc = "<bold>Hello<bold> World";
new Text(desc);
```

Comment: You shouldnt be using those tags anymore.  Its archaic and I believe is depreciated.  That being said....  What happens when you pass A string into the Text Constructor?  My bet....  It will show the text but not render the HTML.  Reason being:  Its a Text object.  There isnt any html involved..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I bold (or format) a piece of text within a paragraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557139/how-do-i-bold-or-format-a-piece-of-text-within-a-paragraph)

Comment: You can also use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_markdown, https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_html_view

Comment: You can make your use Rich Text Widget with the formatting done like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61253256/12347300

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [flutter_html_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_html_view) package for that.

`String html = '<bold>Hello<bold> World';`

`new HtmlTextView(data: html);`

If you just want different styles you can use a `RichText` widget with `TextSpans` like [this](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html).

```
new RichText( text: new TextSpan(text: 'Hello ', style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style, children:          
<TextSpan>[
new TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)), 
new TextSpan(text: ' world!'), 
], ), )
```

Answer (score 4):

StyledText widget can be used for this.

[image]

```
StyledText(text:desc, 
           styles: { 'bold': ActionTextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)},
          );
```

Comment: The package can be found here: https://pub.dev/packages/styled_text

Answer (score 3):

You can have a RichText widget, which can take TextSpan as its child. TextSpan can then take multiple TextSpan as its children, and each TextSpan can have its own styles and gesture detectors. An example of how to crate "read more" privacy statement with onTap gesture detector is below. This will give an output as shown below and when clicked on "Read" the app will be routed to '/privacy' page.

[image]

```
class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  TapGestureRecognizer _routeToPrivacy;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _routeToPrivacy= TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = routeToPrivacy;
  }

  void routeToPrivacy() {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/privacy');
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          child: Column(  
              RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue.shade900,
                      fontFamily: GoogleFonts.lato().fontFamily),
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'By signing up you accepts our privacy policy. ',
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                        recognizer: _routeToPrivacy,
                        text: "Read",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.red.shade500,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [simple_rich_text](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_rich_text) package.

```
SimpleRichText("*Hello* World")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [styled_text](https://pub.dev/packages/styled_text) package then this is what you can get:

[image: Styled Text Preview]

```
StyledText(
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 18,
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
  text: '<i>Please</i> make sure you <u><b>verify your email</b></u> before <s>posting</s>',
  tags: defaultStyledTextTags,
)

final defaultStyledTextTags = {
  'b': StyledTextTag(
    style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
  'u': StyledTextTag(
    style: const TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
  ),
  's': StyledTextTag(
    style: const TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
  ),
  'i': StyledTextTag(
    style: const TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
  ),
};
```