# RichText does not style text as expected

Tags: flutter

Just created a project with:

```
> flutter create simple
```

and added a `RichText` widget,
but the result it is not what I expect: a default styled text with only the word bold in bold.
On my android device I get instead:

[image]

full main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new RichText(
              text: new TextSpan(
                text: 'Hello ',
                style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  new TextSpan(
                      text: 'bold',
                      style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  new TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            new Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

What am I missing? From where does it came this "red" theme?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The usage of `DefaultTextStyle.of(context)` would look if there is any `DefaultTextStyle` parent and fetch style from the parent. So, try wrapping the whole `HomePage` widget in a `DefaultTextStyle` widget with some style. Or make `RichText` a separate widget and wrap in `DefaultTextStyle`.

Example:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            DefaultTextStyle(style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title, child: RichWidget()),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RichWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'Hello ',
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
              text: 'bold',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks, it works! What I don't understand is why a default style has to be explicitly declared. I did not find a place documenting clearly how RichText and DefaultTextStyle fit togheter. Some pointers to docs?

Comment: I suppose there is no proper doc yet. You can check [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12841). Do not interpret that `DefaultTextStyle` would have some style by default. It is just another inherited widget like `Theme` or `Scaffold` that allows its children to access its properties with `context`.

Answer (score 141):

What you can do now is much simpler.

If you want to create a `RichText` with default `TextStyle`, just use `Text.rich`:

```dart
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'Hello '),
      TextSpan(
        text: 'bold',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: This is much better now, Thanks

Comment: @albert221 Can I define RichText and TextSpan theme in main.dart? Kindly suggest albert221. Thanks

Comment: @Kamlesh yes, you can. Use Theme for that

Comment: How can I define RichText and TextSpan theme in main.dart? Kindly suggest albert221. Thanks.

Comment: RichText is lower level of text drawing. So that, It doesn't come with your precious textTheme. You can use Text.rich for a simpler and higher level solution.

Answer (score 5):

```
  RichText(
      text: const TextSpan(
        text: 'Hello',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Your App Font Family',
        ),
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: 'Bold',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: 'word',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

You have to give the font family externally when you use RichText Widget, It is not taking the default font family from your app config.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Stateful Widget and found your text style of showDialog's content does not works as expectation. It maybe you are accessing the wrong context like i experience now.

```dart
class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyScreen> createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder( // this can be anything according to your situation
      builder: (context) {
        return TextButton(
          onPressed: showPopup,
          child: const Text('Show popup'),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> showPopup() async {
    await showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16).r,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: const Text(
              'A Dialog descriptions',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

To fix this, you need to use context from your builder or anything what you are using. Then add `BuildContext` parameter in the method `Future<void> showPopup(BuildContext context);`. And just simply call `onPressed: ()=> showPopup(context),`. This way is ensure you accessing right context rather than directly accessing from the framework state.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: ()=> showPopup(context),
    );
  ...
}

Future<void> showPopup(BuildContext context);
```