# Text overflowing in row when Stack is a parent

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a row widget with two texts widgets inside, however the text keeps overflowing out of screen instead of going right under it. Why is this happening and how can I avoid this?

[image]

```dart
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40.0),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/images/main_cover.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Stack(children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20,0,20,0),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _launchURL(),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          DefaultText(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white, weight: FontWeight.normal, textData: "By clicking the \"Register\", button confirm that you accept the application"),
                          DefaultText(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.blue, weight: FontWeight.normal, textData: "terms of service and privacy policy."),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
            
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include an image what are you trying to archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Flexible as below:

```
Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child:DefaultText(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white, weight: FontWeight.normal, textData: "By clicking the \"Register\", button confirm that you accept the application"),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child:
              DefaultText(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.blue, weight: FontWeight.normal, textData: "terms of service and privacy policy."),
            ),

          ],
        )
```

This will warp your text.

**But I suggest you should use RichText.**

```
RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
            text: 'By clicking the \"Register\", button confirm that you accept the application',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
            children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(text: 'Terms and policy',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blueAccent, fontSize: 18),
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                      // navigate to desired screen
                    }
              )
            ]
        ),
      ),
```

**Update**:
You can also use library **html** https://pub.dev/packages/html

Comment: it creates two columns with around 50% width

Comment: Columns OR Rows ?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/vqbbf6L.png , the texts should be under eachother and full width

Comment: User RichText widget

Comment: Seems fine, but for some reason TextSpan doesn't load my default apps font

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379194/richtext-does-not-style-text-as-expected This link may help

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your children in `Flexible()` widget

Like this:

```
Flexible(
   Text()
),
```

Answer (score 0):

A `row` aligns it's children horizontally, which means your first `DefaultText` widget is rendered and the second one on the right of it.

What you can do is wrap both children in `Expanded` and make the text overflow fading and use `Text` instead of DefaultText :

```
Stack(children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20,0,20,0),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _launchURL(),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(child:Text(style:TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,overflow: TextOverflow.fade),"By clicking the \"Register\", button confirm that you accept the application")),
                          Expanded(child:Text(style:TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,overflow: TextOverflow.fade) ,"terms of service and privacy policy.")),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
            
          ),
        ]),
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/vqbbf6L.png Not the effect Im looking for

Comment: @spunk tell me exactly how is it rendering ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Flexible` in the Row.

```
 Example:Row(
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: DefaultText(
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            weight: FontWeight.normal,
                            textData:
                                "By clicking the \"Register\", button confirm that you accept the application"),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        child: DefaultText(
                            fontSize: 12.0,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            weight: FontWeight.normal,
                            textData: "terms of service and privacy policy."),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `Container` in a `Flexible` to let your `Row` know that it's ok for the Container to be `narrower` than its `intrinsic width`. `Expanded` will also work.