# How can i achieve this half bold text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-text

Does anyone know how I can get this half-bolded effect using Flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RichText`

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: // style text,
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

[Read this doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) and check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379194/richtext-does-not-style-text-as-expected)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RichText` widget like below.

```
RichText(
   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
   text: TextSpan(children: [
   TextSpan(text: "Are you sure you want to delete ", style: black16w700),
   TextSpan(text: "Broker Account?", style: black16w500)
]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var text = RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
   
    style: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 14.0,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'NonBOld'),
      TextSpan(text: 'Bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Try TextSpan widget having children.

Answer (score 0):

use the richtext widget property as follows

```
Text.rich(
    TextSpan(
      style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        fontSize: 52,
        color: const Color(0xff7a7a7a),
      ),
      children: [
        TextSpan(
          text: 'arch',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          ),
        ),
        TextSpan(
          text: 'Incubator',
        ),
      ],
    ),
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [leancode_markup](https://pub.dev/packages/leancode_markup) package. Then your code should look like this:

```
MarkupText(
  'arch[b]Incubator[/b]',
  tagStyles: DefaultMarkupTheme.basicTags,
),
```