# Hi i have simple code in flutter where i want return in sentence formatted bold or colored word.My text is return without formatting it looks bad

Tags: flutter, dart, dartpad

Here is my code where return response is that text which i want to be formatting. At start program i choose option after what i choose it will display this answer.

```
String getResponse(String selectedOption) { // Pass the selected option as a parameter
  String response;
  if (selectedOption.toLowerCase().contains("5 secret rules")) {
    response =
        "5 secret rules to be succesful";
  } else if (selectedOption.toLowerCase().contains("life")) {
    response =
        "The meaning of life .";
  } else if (selectedOption.toLowerCase().contains("joke")) {
    response =
        "Why don't scientists trust atoms? Because they make up everything.";
  } else {
    response =
        "I'm sorry, I didn't understand that. Can you please try again?";
  }
    
  
    return response;
  }
```

Thank youfor help.

Itried many ways really dont know how to do it. Actuall result is unformatted text. I want it to look better some word can be bold other word in different color.

Comment: i don't understand, can you give us full code & some testcases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I bold (or format) a piece of text within a paragraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557139/how-do-i-bold-or-format-a-piece-of-text-within-a-paragraph)

Comment: Thank you for your answer i must redo all code finally